Can't find a cookie for my domain to use for authentication
I am learning how to do a JWT authentication process with React and NodeJS( Express). I used postman to execute the following function
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

// Secret key used to sign the tokens
const secretKey = '/Phc{m=MG$nv)UNb&j8k?djaRD)-FQ/3QK,aYT}9a/):FmSk2H';

// Verify token function
function verifyToken(token) {
  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, secretKey);
    return decoded; // Token is valid
  } catch (error) {
    return null; // Token is invalid
  }
}

// Route for token verification
router.post('/verifyToken', (req, res) => {
  const { accessToken } = req.body;
  if (!accessToken) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Access token is required' });
  }
  const decodedToken = verifyToken(accessToken);
  if (decodedToken) {
    // Token is valid, send success response
    return res.json({ isValid: true });
  } else {
    // Token is invalid, send error response
    return res.json({ isValid: false });
  }
});

// Export the router
module.exports = router;
We initialize the route in the entry file of our node app

const verifyTokenRouter = require('./routes/VerifyToken')
app.use("/", verifyTokenRouter)


// Import necessary modules
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const db = require('./models');

// Middleware
app.use(express.json());

app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000', // Allow requests only from http://localhost:3000
    credentials: true // Allow cookies to be sent with the request
  }));

With postman the request works just fine , but I have a function to automatically take our cookie and execute verifyToken via axios , however baffling enough it fails because it cannot find the cookie for in my document
useEffect(() => {
    // Function to retrieve the value of a cookie by name and domain
    function getCookie(name, domain) {
      const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
      for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
        // Check if this cookie matches the desired name and domain
        if (cookie.startsWith(name + '=') && cookie.includes(`Domain=${domain}`)) {
          // Return the value of the cookie
          return cookie.substring(name.length + 1);
        }
      }
      // Return null if the cookie is not found
      return null;
    }

    // Retrieve the access token cookie from localhost domain
    const accessToken = getCookie('accessToken', 'localhost');

    // Example usage
    if (accessToken) {
      // Make a request to your server's API endpoint for token verification
      axios.post('http://localhost:3001/auth/verifyToken', { accessToken })
        .then(response => {
          const isValid = response.data.isValid; // Assuming the server returns the verification result
          console.log('Token verification result:', isValid);
          if (isValid) {
            console.log('Sign In successful');
          } else {
            console.log('Sign In failed');
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error verifying token:', error);
        });
    } else {
      console.error('Access token cookie not found');
    }
  }, []);

So just to clarify again only the last block of code fails it returns the else error of App.jsx:48 Access token cookie not found so getCookie accessToken fails for some reason ? Initially I thought it may not know the domain so I added this line if (cookie.startsWith(name + '=') && cookie.includes(Domain=${domain}`)) I also tried to remove the name of the cookie and identify by the domain name alone but i still have the same error.
I'm really not sure what I am doing wrong
I searched for similar issues but not one of them really match my case.
